# jQuery update time interval on click

Tags: jquery

I have an animation within a **#animation-section** that will fade out after 15 seconds. like the working code below:

```
var time = 15000;

$('#animation-section').delay(time).fadeOut(600);
```

Because 15 seconds is a long time in this fast internet age. In addition, there should be a way to skip this animation by pressing a button (#skip).

```
$( "#skip" ).click( function () {      
        time = 500;
        $('#animation-section').delay(time).fadeOut(600); 
} );
```

When this #skip button is presses, the animation should stop and the **#animation-section** should immediately fadeOut, I did try to achieve this by updating the time variable from 15 seconds to .5 seconds, but it seems like the time is already set to 15 seconds.

**How can I make this click function update or overwrite the #animation-section time delay?**

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/stop/ or https://api.jquery.com/finish/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the .delay() function of jQuery is not the best thing to do here, because you can't break/stop the jQuery delay.

[Source](https://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Using the [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function will do.

Try this:

```
var time = 15000;
setTimeout(() => { //this sets a 'delay' of 15000ms(time)
    $("#animation-section").fadeOut(600);   
}, time);

$("#skip").click(function() {
    $("#animation-section").fadeOut(600); //directly fades out the #animation-section without any delay
});
```

Example:

```js
var time = 15000;
setTimeout(() => { //this sets a 'delay' of 15000ms(time)
  $("#animation-section").fadeOut(600);
}, time);

$("#skip").click(function() {
  $("#animation-section").fadeOut(600); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="animation-section" style="background: blue; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="skip">Skip animation</a>
```